# Listing Docker Images without registry URI

Tags: bash, awk

I have a private container registry behind a firewall that will need some Google registry images. To make sure things are updated sanely, I'm writing a mirror script in Bash. I have one line that lists the images without their registry URIs, but it's overly complicated and I am piping through 3 awk statements.

```
docker images | awk '{printf("%s\:%s\n", $1, $2)}' | awk 'NR>1' | awk -F '/' '{print $3}'
```

First awk statement:

```
$ docker images | awk '{printf("%s\:%s\n", $1, $2)}'
REPOSITORY:TAG
gcr.io/google_containers/skydns:2015-10-13-8c72f8c
```

Second awk statement:

```
$ docker images | awk '{printf("%s\:%s\n", $1, $2)}' | awk 'NR>1'
gcr.io/google_containers/skydns:2015-10-13-8c72f8c
```

Third awk statement:

```
$ docker images | awk '{printf("%s\:%s\n", $1, $2)}' | awk 'NR>1' | awk -F '/' '{print $3}'
skydns:2015-10-13-8c72f8c
```

How can I reduce this to one awk statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the purpose of the second command is to skip the `REPOSITORY:TAG` table header, which would always be the first line of the `docker images` output.  You can therefore combine the first two `awk` commands as:

```
awk 'NR > 1 { printf("%s:%s\n", $1, $2) }'
```

To keep just the trailing part of the `REPOSITORY` field, you could do `gsub('.*/', '', $1)`.  Note that that is not the same as `awk -F '/' '{print $3}'`, but likely better.

Therefore, I would write the solution as

```
docker images | awk 'NR > 1 { gsub('.*/', '', $1); printf("%s:%s\n", $1, $2); }'
```